# If any two numbers' multiplication in array is greater than 26 return true, otherwise false

Tags: javascript, dictionary, comparison

Return the string true if any two numbers can be multiplied so that the answer is greater than double the sum of all the elements in the array. If not, return the string false.

```
let arr = [2,2,2,2,4,1]
function SumMultiplier(arr) { 

  let sum = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc +item,0)
  let trueStr = "true"
  let falseStr = "false"
  let double = sum*2
  let arrLength = arr.length
  let i = 0
  let j = 1
  while(i < arrLength){
    let multi = arr[i] * arr[j]
    if(double < multi) {
      j++
    }else{
      return trueStr
    }
  }
  return falseStr 

}
```

i found double the sum of all elemets in array,  but cant solve multiplaction each element in array.

Comment: You don't need to multiply each element to each other element. Just find the two largest elements and multiply those two.

Answer (score 0):

You can find tho largest element in the array, multiply them and then compare result with the doubled sum.

```js
function SumMultiplier(arr) {
  const target = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0) * 2;
  const [largest, secondLargest] = findTwoLargest(arr)

  return largest * secondLargest > target ? "true" : "false"
}

function findTwoLargest(arr) {
  let largest = arr[0];
  let secondLargest = -Infinity;

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
      secondLargest = largest;
      largest = arr[i];
    } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i] < largest) {
      secondLargest = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return [largest, secondLargest];
}

console.log(SumMultiplier([2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't care if the number multiplies by itself, try using nested loops, it's easier. This way you check every element with the other ones including itself.

Something like:

```
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

   for (var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

       if(arr[i] * arr[j] > sumDouble){

            return 'true';
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @tkausl comented

```
let arr = [2,2,2,2,4,1]

function SumMultiplier(arr) {
   let sum = arr.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + 2*a, 0);
   let b = arr.slice(0).sort((e1, e2) => e2 - e1)
   let r = b[0] * b[1]
   return (r > sum) ? "true": "false"
}
```

after @Nina Scholz coment modify sort() to sort((e1, e2) => e1 - e2)

@tatactic coment => sort((e1, e2) => e2 - e1)

Comment: try with `10` as value for sorting ...

Comment: sort() sort as strings...

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ read this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp to learn how to sort numbers